# texttt, textsc, and textmd are uncompatible with beamer slides

Tags: beamer

I tried `beamer`'s slide syntax for the `\texttt`, `\textsc`, and `\textmd` commands, and it didn't work. It works for the other commands. The only way I found to have typewriter text on the second slide was `\only<2>{\ttfamily}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    %These work
    \textbf<2>{Bold in the second slide}\\
    \textit<2>{Italic in the second slide}\\
    \textsf<2>{Sans-serif in the second slide}\\
    \textsl<2>{Slanted in the second slide}\\
    \emph<2>{Emphasized in the second slide}\\
    %These don't
    \textrm<2>{Roman in the second slide}\\
    \textsc<2>{Small caps in the second slide}\\
    \texttt<2>{Typewriter in the second slide}\\
    \textmd<2>{Medium-weight in the second slide}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Second slide]

Why do these three commands do not work with slides?

Comment: None of the mentioned `\text...` commands are adapted for `beamer` syntax, that's all.

Comment: @Fran That's the second slide. The first one has the same characters, but it's all normal text.

Comment: @Kurzd I did not say anything. I was in another galaxy :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither `\textmd`, `\textsc` and `\texttt` have been defined with overlay specifications for `beamer` (don't ask why, most likely because that at least `\texttt` and `\textsc` does not look nice in a presentation, but this is a guess only!)

`\textsc` will not work with the given fonts at all, so I used `lmodern` in addition.

The `beamer` system provides sophisticated versions of `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` using the overlay specification (see the examples.) Please note that the last argument number is actually meant for the overlay.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\textmdorig\textmd
\let\textscorig\textsc
\let\textttorig\texttt

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}


\renewcommand<>{\textmd}[1]{%
  \only#2{\textmdorig{#1}}%
}
\renewcommand<>{\textsc}[1]{%
  \only#2{\textscorig{#1}}%
}
\renewcommand<>{\texttt}[1]{%
  \only#2{\textttorig{#1}}%
}


\begin{frame}
    %These work
    \textbf<2>{Bold in the second slide}

    \textit<2>{Italic in the second slide}

    \textsf<2>{Sans-serif in the second slide}

    \textsl<2>{Slanted in the second slide}

    \emph<2>{Emphasized in the second slide}

    \textrm<2>{Roman in the second slide}

    \textsc<2>{Small Caps In The Second Slide}

    \texttt<2>{Typewriter in the second slide}

    \textmd<2>{Medium-weight in the second slide}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I vote Christian :).

Comment: To mimic other commands, I prefer `\renewcommand<>{\textsc}[1]{\alt#2{\textscorig{#1}}{#1}}`.

Comment: ...or, as proposed in beamer guide, `\renewcommand<>{\textsc}{\only#1{\beameroriginal{\textsc}}}`.